# I am looking for alternatives to the phrase "way too" or "far too" as in "Way too often..."

Tags: phrases, word-usage, synonyms

I am editing a work written for professions and have come across a sentence beginning "Way too often I encounter ..." First, this seems very colloquial. In doing some research on google ([alternative to "way too"], [alternatives to saying "way too", grammar girl and grammarist, which did not not pull anything, I came here. Urban Dictionary states: A phrase originating from Welland, Ontario, Canada. The phrase means to do/be something to a great extent. The alternatives are professional than what I am starting with: [urban dictionary.com]. Any help appreciated. This is the first question I've posted; Apologize for posting errors.

Comment: Take the the advice of one of my favorite editors, and eliminate superfluous words at every turn.  "Way" and "far" may be safely consigned to the scrap basket.

Comment: Do you and your editor also consider "very" to be superfluous?

Comment: I agree with your comment, Rob_Ster, about being superfluous. Thank you.

Comment: @scott, I was taught to avoid the use of the word "very" because its usually superfluous.

Comment: Urban Dictionary is good for motivation but is not a particularly good source for reliable definitions or provenance.

Answer (score 5):

"Much too" is a more "professional" way of saying "way too."

Answer (score 0):

Since you are a little vague on the  contents are usage and did not give example as to when and what manner it is being used, it leads me to think you are reffering to time in a sense.

Like: She uses the words "way too" way too much and "far too" often.

If I am wrong please let me know and I will do my best to help you with how it is being used. I have done a lot of editing.

Check: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/often

One Word:

Considerably, Consistently, Customarily, Decidedly, Eminently, Exceedingly, Exceptionally, Extremely, Frequently, Generally, Habitually, Intermittently, Notably, Oft, Often, Oftentimes, Recurrently, Regularly, Repeatedly, Routinely, Surpassingly, Usually, Very

More than One Word:

A great deal, As a rule, At regular intervals, At times, Every now and then, Fairly often, In many instances, Many a time, Time after time, Time and again, Time and time again, Very often

Hope these help. If you need more help, please feel free to ask.